# Can I forward template arguments of a derived class to the base in CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Suppose I have a derived class `Derived`. As well as taking template parameters, `Derived` is a derived class of `Base`, which in turn is templated on `Derived`.

The following illustrates an example of a working solution:

```
template <int i, typename T>
class Derived : public Base<Derived<i,T>>
{
};

template <typename DerivedType>
class Base
{
};
```

When the template argument list of `Derived` gets large, however, this becomes a pain, because coders who want to add derived classes to the library have to write the template arguments twice. Is there anyway of somehow automating this?

Here's what I'm after (the following doesn't compile because `this` doesn't exist yet, but it illustrates what I'm looking for):

```
template <int i, typename T>
class Derived : public Base<decltype(*this)>
{
};

template <typename DerivedType>
class Base
{
};
```

I'm open to an elegant macro solution (oxymoron perhaps?) if there is no way of achieving this with templates.

Comment: Why is the name of the derived class the same as the name of the base class's template parameter?

Comment: @Beta It's not. I had it as `Derived` earlier but changed it to avoid confusion, maybe you saw an old revision.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't kept up with the editing.

Comment: Are you willing to use something like Boost.Preprocessor?

Comment: You're looking for something like D's [template mixins](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html), but sorry, I know of no C++ solution. I think any macro solution that would be generic enough would be too ugly.

Comment: @TravisGockel If it's a compact and readable solution and if there are no alternatives then yes.

Comment: Still feeling this one out...would this usage be considered "readable"? `GENERATE_CRTP(Derived, Base, ((int)(i))(typename)(T))) { ... }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
template <int i, typename X>
struct Derived
{
   class T : public Base<T> { ... };
};

Derived<2, char>::T x;
```

Comment: I think there's a name clash.

Answer (score 2):

Use a traits class to contain the metadata rather than passing each item in the parameter list.

Here's what I do in a library I'm writing, soon to be open sourced.

First, there's the default traits class to cover the common case. I want to handle a range of common cases so it's also a template, but otherwise it could be a regular class. The parameterization is only what's convenient to the user, not the final detailed implementation parameterization, which instead comprises its contents.

```
template< typename rep_type, unsigned mantissa_values, rep_type fractional_cycles >
struct positive_logarithm_default_traits {
    typedef double conv_basis;
    static constexpr bool range_check = true;
    typedef rep_type rep;

protected:
    static constexpr rep max_rep = std::numeric_limits< rep >::max();
    static constexpr rep unity_rep = mantissa_values * fractional_cycles;

    // Another specialization could overflow to INFINITY and underflow to 0.
    [[noreturn]] static rep underflow() { throw range_error( false ); }
    [[noreturn]] static rep overflow() { throw range_error( true ); }
};
```

Then I define a metafunction to transform one instance of the class to another. It works within the traits class space, which can help compile time by eliminating instantiation of intermediate results if multiple metaprocessing transformations are strung together.

```
// The traits of a logarithm which represents the inverse of another logarithm.
template< typename traits >
struct inverse_traits : traits {
    static constexpr decltype( traits::unity_rep ) unity_rep
        = traits::max_rep - traits::unity_rep;
};
```

Although the traits class usually only contains compile-time data, I'll allow for runtime variation by inheriting from it. In such cases, the traits class may also want to access the state of the derived class. That's essentially CRTP. But, a given traits class might want to service several final derived classes with non-traits parameterization. So I make an additional class with runtime state accessible to the traits class, by `static_cast< logarithm_state_base< traits > >( * this )` — this is functionally equivalent to CRTP but sidesteps a lot of metaprogramming complexity.

```
template< typename traits >
class logarithm_state_base : public traits {
protected:
    typename traits::rep log_value;
};
```

Finally, the derived class provides the same convenient interface to the user as the default traits class interprets. Internally, though, it references all metadata through members inherited from the traits class.

If the user defines their own traits class, then the template parameters before `typename traits_type` (except mantissa_values) are vestigial and unused. An alias template could set them all to `void` to provide a solely traits-based user interface. Alternately, if I anticipated that traits usage would be more popular, I could do it the other way and let traits be the "native" interface and the itemized parameters be the convenience alias.

```
template<
    typename rep, // Underlying representation type
    unsigned mantissa_values, // # distinct values per power of 2
    rep fractional_cycles = std::numeric_limits< rep >::max() / ( mantissa_values * 2 ) + 1,
    typename traits_type = positive_logarithm_default_traits< rep, mantissa_values, fractional_cycles >
>
class static_positive_logarithm
    : public logarithm_state_base< traits_type > {
    static_assert ( std::is_unsigned< typename traits_type::rep >::value,
        "Representation type must be unsigned." );

    …
```

Comment: with your example, we don't see the gain. Instead of repeating argument for base class, you repeat the argument for the default template argument...

Comment: @Jarod42 The template parameters (which may or may not have defaults) are only provided for user convenience. The list will never get large, because the complete set of configurable properties is contained in the traits class, not the parameter list. If you prefer, you can limit all the classes to exactly one template parameter: the traits class.